# missing artifact javax.persistence:ejb:jar:3.0-public_review error in pom.xml

Tags: maven, pom.xml

I created a dynamic web application in eclipse Version: Kepler Service Release 1 using menu. After that I converted it into a maven project using configure -> convert to maven project. Then I did maven->Add dependency and added a few dependencies after searching. But after
adding ejb(javax.persistence) I am getting an error missing artifact javax.persistence:ejb:jar:3.0-public_review whenever I hover over the dependency definition of ejb.
How to fix it? Please also explain the reason for the error.

Here is the generated xml after adding ejb.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>DAO</groupId>
  <artifactId>DAO</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
        <version>3.1rc2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>ejb</artifactId>
        <version>3.0-public_review</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Have you tried to build the project on command line ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion khmarbaise. It says [INFO] Unable to find resource 'javax.persistence:ejb:jar:3.0-public_review' in repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2). Is there any way I can prevent it from coming into search results. I changed the artifactId from ejb to transaction-api and now it works fine.